# F# Microsoft Accelerator 'Failure to create a DirectX 9 device'

Tags: f#, gpgpu, directx-9, microsoft-accelerator

I'm using the Microsoft Accelerator V2 library for some GPU accelerated computational tasks (a Monte Carlo simulation in this particular case) in an F# library. However, when I try and run my code (from a .fsx file in the FSI) I get this error:

```
Microsoft.ParallelArrays.AcceleratorException: Failure to create a DirectX 9 device.
   at Microsoft.ParallelArrays.ParallelArrays.ThrowNativeAcceleratorException()
   at Microsoft.ParallelArrays.DX9Target..ctor()
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002_MonteCarloGPU.main@() in F:\Work\GitHub\qf-sharp\qf-sharp\MonteCarloGPU.fs:line 14
Stopped due to error
```

The code it is failing on is:

```
let dxTarget = new DX9Target();
```

The graphics card on my machine is a NVIDIA Quadro 3000M and my Direct X version is 11.

I also have the Direct X SDK installed.

I thought may have something to do with it specifically trying to create a DirectX 9 device, but nowhere in the accelerator docs does it mention needing Direct X 9 specifically (as opposed to anything higher)

But to be safe I attempted to install Direct X 9 and it told me that it was unable to install it as as higher or more recent version of Direct X was detected on the machine.

I found this thread on MSDN, however the marked answers barely even seem to relate to the question so are relatively unhelpful.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/98600646-0345-4f62-a6c5-f03ac9c77179/ms-accelerator?forum=csharpgeneral

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I am completely lacking in knowledge in this specific area.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: When you say "the graphics card on the machine this code is running on" -- are you running the code on your local machine, or on a remote machine (e.g., via Remote Desktop)?

Comment: Sorry, that is a bit oddly worded when I read it back. It's on my local machine.

Comment: Does the Accelerator SDK include any example projects? If so, try compiling/running those -- that'll help you determine if the problem is with your code or with your machine.

Comment: Hi, yeah I've tried their example code and I get the same error when creating the new DX8Target. Gr!

Comment: I just realized you're running the code in F# interactive. I assume your machine is running 64-bit Windows? If so, you'll also need to [change your settings so `fsi` runs in 64-bit mode](http://richardminerich.com/2013/03/setting-up-fsharp-interactive-for-machine-learning-with-large-datasets/); if not, you'll get strange errors like this when your code (or some library you're calling) tries to P/Invoke some native library.

Comment: No I'm running 32-bit (I know I know, it's a travesty. It was a mistake by Dell that I've never corrected)

Comment: I see the same problem.  The exception has HResult 0x80004001 (Not implemented), which suggests some problem with the driver, but I don't know how to debug it.

Comment: Hey, did you ever find a fix for this?

Comment: @JustinMoser sadly no.  I just wanted to play with the Accelerator out of interest one day, so I gave up after a while :-(